# How to call servlet from a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a question, how to call a servlet from a jsp(chart.jsp) without using `<jsp:include page="/servletURL" />`because I tried before and I don't know if this is the right reason but it crashes when I use this code above.
I put in my doGet() method to retrieve information from DB and populate my dropdownlist (in chart.jsp) using JSTL+option and then redirect to my page (the same page), what I believe is that everytime the browser writes a new page using `c:forEach`tag it calls again my servlet and there is a never ending loop (Again, that's just my presumptions)
Here is my code to make it more clear:

my servlet:

```
ArrayList<Machine> foundMachines = MachineDB.getAllMachines();
request.getSession().setAttribute("foundMachineList", foundMachines);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("charts/chart.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

my jsp:

```
<jsp:include page="/searchServlet" />
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:forEach var="machine" items="${sessionScope.foundMachineList}">
 <option value="${machine.machineId}">${Machine.machineName}
 </option>
</c:forEach>
```

So my question is why my `<jsp:include page="/servletURL" />` tag crashes my page and how to fix it. Any sugestion is welcome

Comment: By any chance, the jsp snippet you have given is from the chart.jsp page?

Comment: No, it is a normal class mapped as "searchServlet"

Comment: +1 for using JSTL and EL instead of Scriplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 response.sendRedirect("//your servlet name");
```

Comment: This method doesn't make my page crash however doesn't create my dropdownlist as well

Comment: It was my error... I forgot to insert the tag `<select>` thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is not related but change

```
    ${Machine.machineName} to ${machine.machineName}
```

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how I did that, but it was working, now it just writes the machineName instead of creating my dropdown, it is like printing all names as a simple text

Comment: Sorry I forgot the `select` tag!

Comment: if the response is correct mark it as finish please